# What is the function that converts uniform to exponential?

Tags: probability, distributions

What is the function that converts uniform to exponential with the following assumption?

Suppose the random variable $X$ follows the arbitrary cumulative distribution $F_{x}(x)$. If the random variable $U$ is defined by $U = F_x(x)$, $U$ has a uniform distribution between zero and one.

Answer (score 2):

You need the function $F_x^{-1}(u)=x$. You can see how to generate exponential RV from uniform RV [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#/Computational_methods) as follows:
$$F^{-1}(u)=-\frac{\ln(1-u)}{\lambda}$$
where $\lambda$ is the rate parameter of exp. RV.

Comment: sorry can you give the proof

Comment: Sorry, this seems like a homework problem. Apologies if not. That's why I didn't provide the whole solution, but tried to point you in the right direction. Why don't you give it a try, write the CDF of exp RV (which can be obtained from wikipedia) and solve for $F(x)=u$, i.e. obtain $x$?

Comment: yes you were right that was easy but this is not a homework :|

Comment: now I want to code a  function in matlab that does the following
 Inside it by producing Uniform random variables samples (using the rand command) and applying the function g(U) on them to obtain examples of exponential random variables. The output of the function will be a vector N × 1 and Landa is an exponential random variable parameter